# Can anyone help validate my FEM results?

Tags: finite-element-method

Quick background, I'm a programmer not an engineer, but I do have some background in physics and maths - I understand I may have been a little ambitious with this project, but its my master dissertation at this point and I'm in a little deep!

I have made a 3D FEA solver written in C++ but the resulting displacements and von Mises for most models I make are either sort of in the right area, or miles off in their results. My current process is the following:

1. Discretisation of the model - this is easy in my case as the solver is meant for use on cube voxels so its already split up, I just turn each cube into 6 congruent tetrahedra (I read that you can use cube elements, but couldn't find out how to build the stifness matrix for them.)
2. Calculating the stiffness matrix of each element
3. Assemble the global stiffness matrix K from all the elements
4. Apply given constraints to K by zeroing out the rows/columns of restrained vertices.
5. Solve for displacement U using Conjugate Gradient with a given force vector F
6. Use the general von Mises equation to calculate stress in each element, then average the stress over the 6 tetrahedral for each voxel cube.

Here's an example result of my system at step 2 - the stiffness matrix for a tetrahedron with Poisson's ratio 0.28, Young's modulus 200, vertices: 1:(0,0,1) 2:(1,0,0) 3:(0,0,0) 4:(1,1,0)

Result (values have been rounded to 2SF so they got output neatly):

```
 13   0   0   0   0  13 -13   0 -13   0   0   0
  0  13   0   0   0 -13   0 -13   0   0   0  13
  0   0  43  17 -17   0 -17   0 -43   0  17   0
  0   0  17  56 -30   0 -43  13 -17 -13  17   0
  0   0 -17 -30  56   0  17 -13  17  13 -43   0
 13 -13   0   0   0  26 -13  13 -13   0   0 -13
-13   0 -17 -43  17 -13  56   0  30   0 -17   0
  0 -13   0  13 -13  13   0  26   0 -13   0 -13
-13   0 -43 -17  17 -13  30   0  56   0 -17   0
  0   0   0 -13  13   0   0 -13   0  13   0   0
  0   0  17  17 -43   0 -17   0 -17   0  43   0
  0  13   0   0   0 -13   0 -13   0   0   0  13
```

So with that all said, my first question would be is there anything obvious I'm missing out here?

My second question is can someone validate if this first step of calculating the element stiffness matrix is even correct/how I would go about validating that myself? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Main sources I used to cobble together my implementation:
https://academic.csuohio.edu/duffy_s/CVE_512_12.pdf
https://caendkoelsch.wordpress.com/2017/12/03/how-are-stiffness-matrices-assembled-in-fem
https://podgorskiy.com/spblog/304/writing-a-fem-solver-in-less-the-180-lines-of-code

Comment: If that is supposed to be a stiffness matrix, all the diagonal terms should be positive not negative. Have you checked if the four nodes of the element are numbered "right handed" or "left handed"? That might explain why the code "sometimes works" if you got lucky and the elements were numbered consistently.

Comment: That's good to know thanks! And yes turns out I'd made a mistake in the ordering - although fixing that doesn't seem to have affected the results all too much - Either way I've updated the results on the main post.

Comment: Think about a systematic way to test it. Start with one cubical voxel. Fix one face, apply a uniform force to the opposite face, set Poisson's ratio = 0, and check the results are "exact". Repeat for fixing the other 5 faces. Then try assembling two elements.  Then add in more things that might go wrong, one at a time. Making a "big" model and getting the wrong answers doesn't usually tell you anything useful. (but you probably discovered that already.)

Comment: Right, so if I'm understanding correctly with a poissons of 0 the deformations should be in the same direction as the applied force? I've tested this with my system and it seems that the displacements are mostly (~90%) in the direction of the force, and the calculated von misses are roughly equal (+-10%) to the total force. Should this margin of error not exist or is it reasonable given the use of an iterative solver?

Comment: Assuming you are using 64-bit arithmetic (and if you aren't, you should be!)  if the analytic solution to the problem is constant stress and strain, the numerical answers should be correct to at least 6 significant figures, and more likely they would be correct to 10 sf or better. Answers that are "roughly equal to within 10%" are just "wrong" IMO.

Comment: Yes I'm using 64bit with Eigen maths library, and yea that makes sense. the discrepancies I get probably point towards some minor mistakes in implementation then. I think I will scale my testing down to a single tetrahedra and try to get results with that which are exact then build from there. Thanks for all the advice, I was really quite stuck and I feel as though I have a lot of avenues to explore now, cheers!